# Chrome doesn't seem to run my script properly... some of the time

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome

I'm developing a website on ASP.NET MVC that's supposed to go live early next month, and I'm having a problem I can't find neither cause nor solution to.

There's one page with an image slider I wrote myself. In general, it works without trouble. It never causes trouble in IE or Firefox, and Firebug doesn't throw any errors ever.
However, Chrome doesn't seem to run the initialisation script properly about 50% of the time. Sometimes it works, sometimes it doesn't. The function that sets the image positions and resizes the body of the slider is the same that gets called on a window resize, just that on initialisation it is called directly from the constructor.

If the initial initialisation fails, the function gets executed properly and the slider works as soon as the window is resized or the page is refreshed (in both cases, the resizing function is called again).

I have no idea where to start looking for the problem. Is there something like firebug for chrome, so I could take a look where things might go wrong? as the problem never occurs in Firefox, firebug is kinda useless in this situation...

Anyways, here's the constructor and the resizing function, in case somebody spots an obvious problem.

constructor:

```
function ImageSlider(container_id, next_button_id, prev_button_id, image_class, fullscreen_close_icon){
this.container = $(container_id);
this.images = this.container.children("img" + image_class);
this.image_comments = this.container.contents("div" + image_class);
this.current_image = 0;

if (!fullscreen_close_icon)
{
    this.close_icon = null;
}
else
{
    this.close_icon = fullscreen_close_icon;

}

this.body_overflow = $("body").css("overflow");             //storing the original overflow of the body, because we're going to hide for the fullscreen view of the image

//initialising images
this.resize();
for (var i = 1; i < this.images.length; ++i)
{
    this.images.eq(i).css("opacity", "0");
    this.image_comments.eq(i).css("opacity", "0");
}

var nextbutton = this.container.find(next_button_id);
var prevbutton = this.container.find(prev_button_id);
if (nextbutton == null || nextbutton.length == 0)
{
    nextbutton = $(next_button_id);
}
if (prevbutton == null || prevbutton.length == 0)
{
    prevbutton = $(prev_button_id);
}
var that = this;
nextbutton.click(function(){that.nextImage()});
prevbutton.click(function () { that.prevImage() });

if (this.close_icon != null)
{
    this.container.click(function () { that.fullScreenImage() });
}
$(window).resize(function(){that.resize()});}
```

resizing function:

```
ImageSlider.prototype.resize = function () {
var tallestelement = 0;
var tallestsize = 0;
var topoffset = this.images.eq(0).outerHeight(true) + this.image_comments.eq(0).outerHeight(true);
for (var i = 1; i < this.images.length; ++i) 
{
    //position the current element at the top of the container
    this.images.eq(i).css("top", (topoffset * -1));
    this.image_comments.eq(i).css("top", (topoffset * -1));
    //measure the height of the current element, image and text
    var elementheight = this.images.eq(i).outerHeight(true) + this.image_comments.eq(i).outerHeight(true);
    //add height of the current element to the total offset
    topoffset = topoffset + elementheight;
    //check if the current element is the tallest so far in the slider
    if (elementheight > tallestsize)
    {
        tallestsize = elementheight;
        tallestelement = i;
    }
}

//resize the container to fit the tallest element
this.container.css("height", this.images.eq(tallestelement).outerHeight(true) + this.image_comments.eq(tallestelement).outerHeight(true) + "px");}
```

And the call to the constructor in the cshtml:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    var slider = new ImageSlider("#slider_image_wrapper", "#upbutton", "#downbutton", ".image", "@Url.Content("~/Content/Images/close.png")");
});
```

I almost get the feeling that $(document).ready gets called too early before all the ids are created, but I have no way of verifying that.

Comment: The title of your question has to be one of the most, if not the most, broad title I have EVER seen on this site.

Comment: Chrome has amazing developer tools - press F12.

Comment: It looks like your resize function depends on images having a complete `outerHeight` — but if it gets run at `$(document).ready`, these images may not have been fully loaded.  Have you verified that your function runs at all? And if it runs, if the `elementheight` for each image looks OK?

Comment: Also, you really don't like to put semi-colons in your script... And you should also note that when you compare things to 0 or null, you *should* be using `===` and `!==`, not just `==` and `!=`

Comment: Yes, you're the man! I wasn't aware that $(document).ready gets called so early. Still learning the ropes here, really. I've moved the first resizing to window.onload(), now everything works fine. So... the problem that it only happened in Chrome was... that chrome gets the DOM ready a lot faster than everyone else? huh...

Comment: It's chrome, it's just that awesome.

Comment: @ctwheels: uhm... am I missing semi-colons somewhere? I can't spot any...

Comment: They are not necessarily necessary (strong wording) but, use jsfiddle.net and paste your code, then click the button at the top that says JSHint. If a popup saying "JSHint Valid!" shows up, you're doing something properly in terms of syntax. It's a good way to check your code fast for any syntax errors and it even tells you on what line the error is!!! Amazing!

Answer (score 0):

i had the same issue with my extension so i put the delay around 3 seconds in my script through setInterval